# How to ignore a specific character input from your keyboard?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xmodmap, xev

My laptop's keyboard has malfunctioned, and so whenever I press spacebar the computer gets input as if I pressed spacebar and page-down at the same time.

I tried using `xev` to figure out which character keycode to disable through `xmodmap -e 'keycode NUMBER = NoSymbol'` but that still didn't work as needed.

I want some way to make the OS completely ignore the fact that the page-down button is getting triggered.

```
xev
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x178, subw 0x0, time 16645657, (-273,111), root:(415,310),
    state 0x10, keycode 117 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x178, subw 0x0, time 16645658, (-273,111), root:(415,310),
    state 0x10, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So I tried `sudo xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = NoSymbol'` and also previously`sudo xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = 0x0000'` if I do that I can make the xev output change to the following:

```
xev
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x178, subw 0x0, time 16645657, (-273,111), root:(415,310),
    state 0x10, keycode 117 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x178, subw 0x0, time 16645658, (-273,111), root:(415,310),
    state 0x10, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

But the laptop still seems to function like before, and the page down button still gets triggered. I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad T560 with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hey Maxim Hermez. Please mention some details in the question like name and model of laptop, Ubuntu version, etc. (use the [edit] feature)

Comment: I've just edited the post for more details, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Nice! Can you please try `xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol'`? Yes, NoSymbol eight times, so that the key does not get triggered if a modified is pressed too.

Comment: That gave the same result as one NoSymbol :/

Comment: Does the behavior change if you turn off Numlock? (I imagine it is on because state says 0x10).

Comment: The state does change to 0x0 without NumLock but the rest was unchanged